# Media Query cannot override previous styling?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm currently trying to override a piece of styling made earlier in my code to my `section-header` with the padding, but having difficulty in doing so. I'm trying to center the section header on desktop sizess only.

My original `section-header` is like this:

```
  .section-header {
    padding-left: 10%;
  }
```

And my media query is like this:

```
@media #{$desktop} {
  .section-header {
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

I've already used `!important` but my mentor tells me to avoid it. How can I override this and make this change?

Comment: try specifying `section-header` preceded by its element. For example, if it is a division then `div.section-heading`.

Comment: Check that: 1) media query expression is valid 2) css code with media query is _below_ original css code

Answer (score 0):

CSS works in multiple ways and can become a mess which is why your mentor mentioned not using "!important" where possible.

One thing to note is if your section rule is after your media query rule, it will override the media query rule.

Also, consider specificity. The more specific you are with your targeting the more important that rule is.

Quick question. Have you opened it up in Inspect to see whether it's even showing? So possible cache clear issue etc?

If it shows in inspect element, it might worth checking whether there is something with higher specificity overriding it.

It's hard to give a fix above the above without seeing but that won't be accepted on here...